# Is this an abuse/misuse of Move Semantics?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

When people usually discuss or use move semantics, it's usually in the context of moving two classes of the same type.

Eg:

```
MyObject(MyObject &&obj) { // Implementation }
```

But what if MyObject is for the most part just wrapping an STL container like vector. Would making a move constructor that takes the vector and moves it considered an abuse of the functionality?

```
MyObject(vector<backingtype> &&v) : i_Backing(move(v)) {}
```

I ask this because I'm making a UTF-8 aware json parser which makes heavy use of copying whereas moving the container would be sufficient and faster.

```
auto arrayParseRes = jsonArrayParse(input); // Array parse res
auto jsonArray = JsonArray(arrayParseRes.Parse_Value()); // Currently copying json values
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is nothing at all wrong with moving from an rvalue passed to your constructor into one of your class members. The constructors for `std::pair` and `std::tuple` also do this.

Comment: Thanks for the STL examples. More than enough proof that it's idiomatic for C++.